# 'undefined reference to _M_hook' error when building KleeNet

Tags: c++

When building KLeeNet under ubuntu 12.10, I got following error:

```
MemCpyOptimizer.cpp:(.text+0x2c25): undefined reference to `std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_hook(std::__detail::_List_node_base*)'
MemCpyOptimizer.cpp:(.text+0x2daa): undefined reference to `std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_unhook()'
```

Does anyone have any ideas on these undefined reference errors?

Comment: seems like you're using an old version of compiler

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Finally I found the fault being caused by unreasonable setting of LIBRARY_PATH environment variable thus the compiler failed to find needed libraries

Answer (score 2):

Problem seems to be with `libstdc++` (mine was).
I used newer version of `libstdc++.so.6` (added new path to LIBRARY_PATH).

Answer (score 0):

Due to a target system where I cannot / don't want to exchange libraries, my solution was to use compiler options.

A very simple way was `-static-libstdc++`, but that gave me a huge executable.

My final solution is to utilize `ar` on "libstdc++.a" to extract "list.o" (which contains the 2 functions in question and 2 others) and instruct `ld` to include this whole object (8kB). I expect very few side effects, since in total just 4 functions are statically included (and ELF etc. provide that one implementation is used at runtime). Details:

```
ar x "${TARGET}/x86/lib/gcc/4.6.3/libstdc++.a" list.o
g++ source.cpp -Wl,--whole-archive "./list.o" -Wl,--no-whole-archive # more options...
rm ./list.o
```